# Extension Method for anonymous type

Tags: c#, datatable, extension-methods

I have a `DataTable` and I want to update its record. I want to update record for multiple columns and I want to write extension method for that. I am not sure what parameter it will accept and what it will return. My code

```
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> UpdateColumns(this IEnumerable<object> e, List<string> columns, List<object> values)
    {
        int index = 0;
        var rec = e.First();
        foreach (string col in columns)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting thing like `SetField()` on `rec`. What I am missing?

Comment: Have you considered dynamics? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Well the type of `rec` is `object`... and `object` doesn't have a `SetField` method - it's not clear why you'd expect it to. Additionally, anonymous types are immutable anyway...

Comment: `rec` is of type `object` so you only have access to members of `object`. It is not clear why you have written an extension method for `IEnumerable<object>` if you want it to be for `DataTable`, first thing I would do is cahnge you first parameter to `this DataTable table`.

Comment: I am just playing around extension method, its not really a task :).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in this case rec is type of object so it would not have SetField() method. You should declare the type of IEnumerable<>.
Did you look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336477%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I have a DataTable and I want to update it...

So, you want to write an extension method for your dataTable.

> I want to update record for multiple columns...

And I think you want to update value of a column for all rows of dataTable to a specific value. I can suggest you to use `IDictionary<string, TValue>` instead of separate lists like `List<string> columns, List<object> values`, then the extension method can be something like this:

```
public static void UpdateColumns<TValue>(this DataTable dataTable,
    IDictionary<string, TValue> columnValuePair)
{
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var pair in columnValuePair)
        {
            dataRow[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var columnValuePair = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"ColumnName1", "newValue1" },
    {"ColumnName2", "newValue2" }
};

yourDataTable.UpdateColumns(columnValuePair);
```

> Note that you don't need to return `DataTable` as result of this extension method, and set it to `yourDataTable`.